How to close file explorer when opening a file?
I want to customize my vscode for the keyboard only experience (sort-of).
Right now, if I open my file explorer and select via the arrow keys the needed file and press enter - it opens that file, focuses the editor (explorer gets unfocused) - but it does not close the file explorer.
So I need to press my combination to focus the explorer back, and then press that again - to close the explorer and focus back the editor.
My question is - how  to close the explorer when I open a selected file?
I tried to find the command that is responsible for opening a new file, or an event, but did not find any solution...

I found the solution which worked for myself.
there is explorer.openAndPassFocus. so this command worked for me
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "when": "filesExplorerFocus && foldersViewVisible && !explorerResourceIsFolder && !inputFocus",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "explorer.openAndPassFocus",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
            "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
        ]
    }
}


You can use the runCommands command to run multiple commands.
In this case, there are two commands you want to happen when you press enter:

open the selected file, list.select
close the sidebar, workbench.action.closeSidebar.

To run both commands on enter, use the following keyboard shortcut:
    {
        "key": "enter",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "when": "explorerViewletFocus && filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "list.select",
                "workbench.action.closeSidebar"
            ]
        }
    },

